# How should a minimal Java program look like?

Tags: java, nosuchmethoderror

I wrote the following code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class Party {
    public void buildInvite() {
        Frame f = new Frame();
        Label l = new Label("Party at Tim's");
        Button b = new Button("You bet");
        Button c = new Button("Shoot me");
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.add(l);
    } //more code here...
}
```

I keep getting the following error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: main`

I've tried to add an additional `main (String[] args)` to the code but I still get the same errors.

What additionally I should put in the code and where in the layout should it go?

Comment: Since you claim to be an absolute noob, make sure you compile your java class using _javac filename.java_ before issuing _java filename_

Comment: @Jagat yeah I got that part right. lol. Thanks though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your `main` method looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Beginners with Java and Swing should check out the [Oracle tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/start/index.html). Here's their [Swing Hello World program](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start//HelloWorldSwing.java):

```
package start;

import javax.swing.*;        

public class HelloWorldSwing {
    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }});}}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely take a look at the Oracle tutorial.

Comment: @Craig: there's a lot of good sample code there you can run. also if you want a deadtree book Core Java (http://www.horstmann.com/corejava.html) is a good place to start for Swing.